# Introductory Analysis lecture slides

Tags: mathematical-analysis, lecture-notes

I will be teaching an introductory analysis course (see topics below) and I need some source-code Latex slides or PPT slides, and am willing to choose my textbook based on these slides (rather than, traditionally, the other way around).

Edit: apparently people want to chime in on teaching philosophy. Many publishers include pre-made lecture slides, which go along with the book, that instructors can edit to their needs (hence my request for open source slides). Examples: Pearson includes sets for many math and physics titles; Cengage includes sets with their math titles.

I am simply looking for introductory analysis slides; and by extension, the textbook these slides would fit with. The slides are more important than the textbook; hence why I consider the slides the first priority, and the textbook can follow from that.

(Topics: Sets of Natural Numbers, Rational Numbers, Real Numbers, Completeness Axiom, Sequences, Limit Theorems for Sequences, Monotone Sequences and Cauchy, Sequences, Series, Alternating Series and Integral Tests, Continuity, Properties of Continuous Functions, Sequences and Series Functions, Uniform Convergence, Differentiation and Integration of Power Series, Mean Value Theorem, L’Hopital Rule, Taylor Theorem, Integration)

Comment: There seems to be an unstated assumption here that this is a reasonable way to approach teaching.

Comment: @BenCrowell  Your point? I'm teaching a remote 5-week online course that's already pre-determined as being purely in the format of dictated lecture slides.

Comment: @Nights: I recommend adding that information to the original post, and clearly state your question. This will hopefully lead to some better answers.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing some cultural context, but if the students are already going to be reading and studying from a required textbook, why do you need formal content in slides? Write slides yourself that fill in what you believe they'll have difficulty with -- I assume you have some idea what their background is and what their ability level is, certainly more than random people on the internet would have. Things like what happens if you switch quantifer order in some of the definitions, motivating examples for the concept, standard strategies for solving problems and proving theorems, etc.

Comment: As an example (not real analysis, however) of my last sentence, see the various comments I made and safety checks I used in [the following ODE solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/829541/13130). Or maybe something [like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/109054/13130) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/137743/13130), which are real analysis related. I'm not suggesting you actually try to work in these specific real analysis topics, by the way, but rather I'm using them as examples of how you might want to *supplement* the textbook as appropriate for your students.

Comment: Hey... check this out: https://link.springer.com/search?facet-content-type=%22Book%22&package=mat-covid19_textbooks&facet-language=%22En%22&sortOrder=newestFirst&facet-discipline=%22Mathematics%22&showAll=true  (FREE BOOK!)

Comment: Have you contacted the publisher? They often have such resources for calculus texts; maybe they have some such thing here as well?

Comment: I don't meant to be rude, but, at the possibility of causing offense:  when I am asked to teach a class, it is assumed that I will prepare my own course.  If I want to use slides, then I will prepare them myself.  It seems that you are kind of asking MESE to "do your homework" for you.

Comment: @XanderHenderson you're aware lots of textbooks come with publisher-made powerpoint slides, or maybe not? I am asking for an introductory analysis book that may come with some. Some strange responses here.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro I'm sure you can think of an answer to your own question. Many teachers rely on slides, for reasons that may or may not be practical (i.e. students refuse to read textbooks; slides make the content more succinct; regardless of who's creating the class). I'm guessing you are also a teacher, and as you gather I am already a teacher, your answer is not helpful.

Comment: @Adam I have contacted several publishers; it's interesting that in general they don't seem to know the content of their textbooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I trudged through Pearson's site and found that Lay's *Analysis with an Intro. to Proof* has PowerPoint slides on their resources page. You'll have to get an account with them to download the files, but I think that the process is straightforward for anyone who is verifiably a faculty member.

See https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/program/Lay-Analysis-with-an-Introduction-to-Proof-5th-Edition/PGM279803.html

I know nothing about this book or the slides, pro or con. It does look like the only such book on Pearson's site. (Many others have problem solutions, but no slides.) You should try other publishers such as Cengage or Wiley as well.

I think that the reason that you are getting push-back about this is that lecturing from slides is a fairly atypical approach for what is usually an upper-level proof-based course and is often taught by someone whose research is or was in the area.

Like others, I wouldn't advocate this approach in a normal semester. However, in the comments is is mentioned that this is a 5 week online summer course. It doesn't seem comparable to a normal semester at all; you hopefully have made the learning goals a bit more achievable. Best of luck to you and your students.

Comment: Thanks; I will be checking these out.
Indeed, it's a course in which the topics have already been set up by the university that I've been asked to teach, online (purely with slides; without recourse to say, a document camera), and in 5 weeks.